# Lion Mail 5.0 rejects a POP server. Looking for confirmation and/or workarounds

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, pop

Has anyone else experienced problems logging into POP servers that require plain text password login? Or more importantly found a work around?

(I know that in this day and age a plain text password long for POP is bad, but I have no control over this server)

Based on a packet trace it looks like Mail 5.0 doesn't even try to login based on the settings in the preferences, it just connects queries capability and quits reporting that the server doesn't support "Password" the thing is, there is no required capability for plain Password method, it is a base POP command.

Comment: I filed a bug with Apple.

Comment: Awesome - I'll answer it - feel free to answer yourself with the radar number or edit my answer so people know there is a reason why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

A bug has been filed as this appears to be a software issue.

Radar #9813866 
The issue in this case seems to be that the Mail app takes a stricter view of the CAPA response which older POP deployments may not match. The server isn't reporting the USER command as available, even though it is a basic command.